# Asp.net Web API Filters priority

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have two filters:

```
public class ValidateModelStateFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}

public class AuthorizeRequestAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        // TODO: validate the request

        return await continuation();
    }
}
```

First one is registered in `Global.asax` `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateFilter());
}
```

The second one is added to controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
[AuthorizeRequestAttribute]
public string GetValue(GetValueRequest request)
{
    return _service.GetValue(request.Product_Id);
}
```

Everything works, except the fact that `[AuthorizeRequestAttribute]` gets executed before `[ValidateModelStateFilter]` filter.

How can i make `[ValidateModelStateFilter]` to execute before any other filters?

Answer (score 0):

The IAuthorizationFilter will always be executed first. An option for you would be do your ValidationModelStateFilter logic in a method implementing iAuthorizationFilter, thus ensuring it runs first. 
You've probably solved your problem at this stage anyway.